# Exception being thrown in main without any errors

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, exit-code

I have a Spring Boot application in IntelliJ that was initially configured to start normally like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SpringApplication.run(AccountApiApplication.class, args).close();
}
```

I added a try-catch block in the `main` method to handle any errors that occur during startup (like missing configuration files etc.), and it now looks like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try {
            SpringApplication.run(AccountApiApplication.class, args).close();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
```

After adding this, my application always exits with an exit code of 1. Even when there are no errors. I tried printing the exception that was occurring, and it's this:

```
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler$SilentExitException
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.SilentExitExceptionHandler.exitCurrentThread(SilentExitExceptionHandler.java:90)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.immediateRestart(Restarter.java:184)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:163)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter.initialize(Restarter.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationStartingEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:67)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(RestartApplicationListener.java:45)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.starting(EventPublishingRunListener.java:68)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.starting(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151)
    at edu.iu.es.ebs.AccountApiApplication.main(AccountApiApplication.java:90)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Why am I seeing this exception even though there are no errors in the application? And while we are at it, is there a better way to handle unpredicatable startup errors than adding a try-catch in `main`?

Comment: why are you closing your application with this `.close()` ?

Comment: @pvpkiran Because if I don't, it doesn't exit. I mean it doesn't end with something like "Process finished with exit code 0" or "Process finished with exit code 1". It ends at "Started Application ...". I will be eventually calling the application through a shell script, so I need it to end and return an exit code to the script.

Comment: @lebowski That's a different problem. If you check the spring boot application lifecycle (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-spring-application.html) you can see that is normal that the application will be on "Started Application" when is ready to work. If you need something like "eventual" execute, you should check the `Schedule` functionality

Answer (score 5):

This is a normal way of working Spring Boot application that has `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools` in its dependencies. By default `org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.Restarter` restarts application  immediately after initialization. To get rid of `SilentExitException` you should get rid of restarter by setting property `spring.devtools.restart.enabled` to `false` but I don't think this exception is such a big problem.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, i think that the problem is the call to `close()`. That method can generate a `SilentExitException`, swallowed by `SilentExitExceptionHandlerexample`, as you can see in your Stacktrace.

Second, its better to use the Interface `FailureAnalizer` to catch errors on startup of the application, it can give you more information about what is wrong.

Comment: I tried removing the `close()` method, but I am still getting that exception.